# How to get a bucket for each day between start date and end date fields of a document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, date-range, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have documents as follows in an index in elasticsearch

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "start": "2021-04-20T00:00:00.000000Z",
        "end": "2021-04-22T22:45:20.000000Z",
        "event_type": "A"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "start": "2021-04-23T00:01:00.000000Z",
        "end": "2021-04-26T21:50:20.000000Z",
        "event_type": "B"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "start": "2021-04-27T00:03:30.000000Z",
        "end": "2021-04-29T04:15:30.000000Z",
        "event_type": "A"
    }
]
```

I want to get count of days each `event_type` spanned for in total. For example, for the above documents,
`event_type A` spanned over 3 days in first document with `"Id": 1` from 20th (start) to 22nd (end) and another 3 days in 3rd document with `"Id": 3` from 27th (start) to 29th (end). So I want to get a count of 6 for `event_type A`. `event_type B` spanned over 4 days in 2nd document with `"Id": 2` from 23rd (start) to 26th (end). So, for `event_type B`, I want count as 4.

| event_type | count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 6 |
| B | 4 |

I know how to get count of documents per event type using terms aggregation

```
GET /split_range/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_event_type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "event_type"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to split that document further into multiple buckets for each day between start and end inclusive of start and end and get that count as well?

Answer (score 0):

If the json is somewhat conistent I would always use pandas for this kind of task.

```
data = [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "start": "2021-04-20T00:00:00.000000Z",
        "end": "2021-04-22T22:45:20.000000Z",
        "event_type": "A"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "start": "2021-04-23T00:01:00.000000Z",
        "end": "2021-04-26T21:50:20.000000Z",
        "event_type": "B"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "start": "2021-04-27T00:03:30.000000Z",
        "end": "2021-04-29T04:15:30.000000Z",
        "event_type": "A"
    }
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['end'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['end']).dt.date
df['start'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['start']).dt.date
df["diff"] = (df["end"] - df["start"])
print(df.head())
```

will result in:

```
   Id         end event_type       start   diff
0   1  2021-04-22          A  2021-04-20 2 days
1   2  2021-04-26          B  2021-04-23 3 days
2   3  2021-04-29          A  2021-04-27 2 days
```

Comment: I noticed that it now rounds down, so you will need to add a day. But you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

##### You can use sum sub aggregation with a script as mentioned below.

1. Use a `term` aggregation on the field `event_type` to get the unique event types.
2. Add a `sum` sub aggregation to calculate the sum of days for each event type.
3. Inside the `sum` aggregation provide the `script` to calculate the day difference.

```
GET split_range/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "GroupByEventType": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "event_type",
        "size": 10000,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sumOfDays": {
          "sum": {
            "script": """
                ZonedDateTime start = doc['start'].value;
                ZonedDateTime end = doc['end'].value;
                return start.until(end, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
             """
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Got the below answer when I tried the above query against the sample data set provided in your question.

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "GroupByEventType" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "A",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "sumOfDays" : {
            "value" : 4.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "B",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "sumOfDays" : {
            "value" : 3.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The response contains sub aggregation for each event type which is sum of days.